# How to create a new test class in shortkeys?

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4, junit3

I work with android studio and I remember that I saw in some video tutorial short way to create test class.

It looked like you just put mouse on name of class, right click and something like `create a test` and then pop up where you can choose version of JUnit 3/4 and components which have to be included immideatly to new test class.

But I don't remember where is this button <kbd>Create test class</kbd>

Could you please give me a hint

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found this keys, you requer to put mouse on the name of class that you need to get autogenerated test class

[image]

and than click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

There is a very good short video tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJE0MDKJOow

Answer (score 0):

There is `Ctrl-Shift-T` hotkey or you can use the main menu `Navigate-Test`.